# DB2 Import - how to merge several CSV files

Tags: import, db2

I have several CSV files with the same columns, however, the columns are in different order.

I would like to merge, via "import", all these CSV files.

Please could you help with this import statement? How can I make this import statement match the column order?

Comment: Is your Db2-server running on Unix/Linux Windows?

Answer (score 0):

With Db2 on Unix/Windows, You can use the IMPORT command or the LOAD command . Additionally other ways are possible with the INGEST command.

With IMPORT or LOAD, There are two ways you can do it, either use the "METHOD P" or specify the order of target-columns on the INSERT clause    There are two examples below.

The first example uses "Method P" for import:

there are three CSV files whose three columns are in different order, and a target table with three columns (a,b,c):

```
create table mytab(a integer not null, b integer not null, c integer not null)
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

!cat 1a.csv 
1,2,3

!cat 1b.csv 
99,98,97

!cat 1c.csv 
55,51,59

import from 1a.csv of del method p(1,2,3) insert into mytab
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "1a.csv".

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "1" rows were read from the 
input file.

SQL3221W  ...Begin COMMIT WORK. Input Record Count = "1".

SQL3222W  ...COMMIT of any database changes was successful.

SQL3149N  "1" rows were processed from the input file.  "1" rows were 
successfully inserted into the table.  "0" rows were rejected.


Number of rows read         = 1
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows inserted     = 1
Number of rows updated      = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows committed    = 1


import from 1b.csv of del method p(3,2,1) insert into mytab
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "1b.csv".

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "1" rows were read from the 
input file.

SQL3221W  ...Begin COMMIT WORK. Input Record Count = "1".

SQL3222W  ...COMMIT of any database changes was successful.

SQL3149N  "1" rows were processed from the input file.  "1" rows were 
successfully inserted into the table.  "0" rows were rejected.


Number of rows read         = 1
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows inserted     = 1
Number of rows updated      = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows committed    = 1


import from 1c.csv of del method p(2,1,3) insert into mytab
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "1c.csv".

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "1" rows were read from the 
input file.

SQL3221W  ...Begin COMMIT WORK. Input Record Count = "1".

SQL3222W  ...COMMIT of any database changes was successful.

SQL3149N  "1" rows were processed from the input file.  "1" rows were 
successfully inserted into the table.  "0" rows were rejected.


Number of rows read         = 1
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows inserted     = 1
Number of rows updated      = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows committed    = 1


select * from mytab 

A           B           C          
----------- ----------- -----------
          1           2           3
         97          98          99
         51          55          59

  3 record(s) selected.
```

The second example uses ordered-column targets for the insert to match the column-target order in the CSV file.

```
create table mynewtab(a integer not null, b integer not null, c integer not null)
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

!cat 1a.csv 
1,2,3

!cat 1b.csv 
99,98,97

!cat 1c.csv 
55,51,59

import from 1a.csv of del insert into mynewtab(a,b,c)
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "1a.csv".

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "1" rows were read from the 
input file.

SQL3221W  ...Begin COMMIT WORK. Input Record Count = "1".

SQL3222W  ...COMMIT of any database changes was successful.

SQL3149N  "1" rows were processed from the input file.  "1" rows were 
successfully inserted into the table.  "0" rows were rejected.


Number of rows read         = 1
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows inserted     = 1
Number of rows updated      = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows committed    = 1


import from 1b.csv of del insert into mynewtab(c,b,a)
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "1b.csv".

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "1" rows were read from the 
input file.

SQL3221W  ...Begin COMMIT WORK. Input Record Count = "1".

SQL3222W  ...COMMIT of any database changes was successful.

SQL3149N  "1" rows were processed from the input file.  "1" rows were 
successfully inserted into the table.  "0" rows were rejected.


Number of rows read         = 1
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows inserted     = 1
Number of rows updated      = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows committed    = 1


import from 1c.csv of del  insert into mynewtab(b,a,c)
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file "1c.csv".

SQL3110N  The utility has completed processing.  "1" rows were read from the 
input file.

SQL3221W  ...Begin COMMIT WORK. Input Record Count = "1".

SQL3222W  ...COMMIT of any database changes was successful.

SQL3149N  "1" rows were processed from the input file.  "1" rows were 
successfully inserted into the table.  "0" rows were rejected.


Number of rows read         = 1
Number of rows skipped      = 0
Number of rows inserted     = 1
Number of rows updated      = 0
Number of rows rejected     = 0
Number of rows committed    = 1


select * from mynewtab 

A           B           C          
----------- ----------- -----------
          1           2           3
         97          98          99
         51          55          59

  3 record(s) selected.
```